# How to install BPG (Better Portable Graphics) on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: software-installation, tar, make, images

How do I install BPG (Better Portable Graphics) on Linux Mint 17? I downloaded the tar.gz file from [Fabrice Bellard's website](http://bellard.org/bpg/). The ReadMe file says,

> Edit the Makefile to change the compile options (the default compile options should be OK for Linux). Type 'make' to compile and 'make install' to install the compiled binaries.

I didn't edit the `Makefile`. I opened the terminal in the directory and ran `make`. It returned the following error:

```
gcc -g -Wl,--gc-sections -o bpgdec bpgdec.o libbpg.a -lpng -lrt -lm -lpthread
bpgdec.o: In function `png_save':
/home/ghort/Downloads/libbpg-0.9.5/bpgdec.c:118: undefined reference to 
  `png_set_longjmp_fn'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bpgdec] Error 1
```

I think I read elsewhere that I need to install libpng16 experimental, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`libbpg` depends on version  1.6 of the PNG library, which you cannot install with `apt-get` on Linux Mint 17. This library is incompatible with `libpng12` and needs to be installed from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/1.6.16/) (I used version [1.6.16](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng16/1.6.16/libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz/download))

The additional complication is that if you install PNG 1.6 the `make` of `libbpg` still uses `libpng12-dev` even if you configure PNG 1.6 with `configure --prefix=/usr`. And you cannot just deinstall `libpng12-dev` as `libsdl-image1.2-dev` and `libsdl1.2-dev` depend on it, and those are needed for compiling `libbpg` as well.

You could probably also download and compile the `libsdl-image` and `libsdl1` sources and not install their `-dev` packages. I did not follow that route, I just temporarily removed the files (not the package) from `libpng12-dev` and reinstalled them after I was done (you should be able to copy and paste this on Linux Mint 17):¹

```
# install dev packages needed 
sudo apt-get install -y libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libjpeg8-dev
#### temporarily remove the files from the libpng12 package
# this gives error messages on the directories (that cannot be removed this
# way, which can be ignored.
sudo rm $(dpkg -L libpng12-dev)

# download, configure, make and make install PNG 1.6
wget -O libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.16/libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Flibpng%2Ffiles%2Flibpng16%2F1.6.16%2F&ts=1424607004&use_mirror=garr'
tar xf libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz
pushd libpng-1.6.16
./configure --prefix=/usr
make -j
sudo make install
popd

# download, make and make install BPG
wget http://bellard.org/bpg/libbpg-0.9.5.tar.gz
tar xf libbpg-0.9.5.tar.gz
pushd libbpg-0.9.5
make -j
sudo make install
popd

# reinstall libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng12-dev
```

Of course it would be more appropriate to install PNG 1.6 in parallel to `libpng12-dev` and adapt the sources of `libbpg`, but since you don't recompile the BPG library on a regular basis, IMO this kludge is acceptable.

---

¹ <sub>You could also try and build [libpng16-dev](https://github.com/dimensio/libpng16-deb), but installing that might just remove the `-dev` packages depending on `libpng12-dev`, I did not try that.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I followed your directions. Two things to note: the command sudo rm $(dpkg -L libpng12-dev) didn't work, returning the error that I don't have permission. I went ahead with executing the subsequent steps and I was able to install. I also had to use one last command: sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib I received the error: error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.4 I found the solution [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17059) to this

Comment: I had to use the command `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib` because I was getting the error `error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.4`. I found the solution [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17059).

Comment: @user8547 I should have warned about the `sudo rm` it tries to rm directories but can't which is fine, as they don't interfere.

Comment: Incidentally, to clarify my solution to `error while loading shared libraries: libMagickCore.so.4`. That was an error I received after installing the latest ImageMagick release, so it's not related to the BPG installation.

Answer (score 4):

It's better not to change the officialy installed package libpng12-dev but rather to indicate in the Makefile from libbpg where to find libpng 1.6

So I modify the Anthon's solution :

```
# install dev packages needed 
sudo apt-get install -y libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libjpeg8-dev

# download, configure, make and make install PNG 1.6 (You coul find a newer version like 1.16.18 for me)
wget -O libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.16/libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Flibpng%2Ffiles%2Flibpng16%2F1.6.16%2F&ts=1424607004&use_mirror=garr'
tar xf libpng-1.6.16.tar.xz
pushd libpng-1.6.16
./configure
make -j
sudo make install
#### The installation will take place in /usr/local by default and it's ok !
popd

# download, make and make install BPG
wget http://bellard.org/bpg/libbpg-0.9.5.tar.gz
tar xf libbpg-0.9.5.tar.gz
pushd libbpg-0.9.5

#### edit Makefile and insert the two following directive :
# "CFLAGS+=-I/usr/local/include" after the line CFLAGS+=-I.
# "LDFLAGS+=-L /usr/local/lib" before the line CFLAGS+=-g

make -j
sudo make install
popd
```

That's all folks !

Answer (score 4):

The other answers on here are great, but I wanted to create a completely automated installation script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install -y cmake yasm libjpeg-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev

pushd /tmp
    wget -O libpng-1.6.21.tar.xz "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/older-releases/1.6.21/libpng-1.6.21.tar.gz?ts=$(date +%s)"
    tar xf libpng-1.6.21.tar.xz
    pushd libpng-1.6.21
        ./configure
        make -j
        sudo make install
    popd
    git clone "https://github.com/mirrorer/libbpg"
    pushd libbpg
        patch <<EOF
--- Makefile    2016-02-03 11:43:37.883142427 -0500
+++ Makefile    2016-02-03 11:44:20.867143492 -0500
@@ -41,6 +41,7 @@
 CFLAGS:=-Os -Wall -MMD -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros -fno-tree-vectorize -fomit-frame-pointer
 CFLAGS+=-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT
 CFLAGS+=-I.
+CFLAGS+=-I/usr/local/include
 CFLAGS+=-DCONFIG_BPG_VERSION=\"\$(shell cat VERSION)\"
 ifdef USE_JCTVC_HIGH_BIT_DEPTH
 CFLAGS+=-DRExt__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT
@@ -59,6 +60,7 @@
 else
 LDFLAGS+=-Wl,--gc-sections
 endif
+LDFLAGS+=-L /usr/local/lib
 CFLAGS+=-g
 CXXFLAGS=\$(CFLAGS)
EOF
        make -j
        sudo make install
    popd
popd
sudo ldconfig  # Required for bpgenc to find libpng16.
```